# atoi in java using charAt

Tags: java

I know that one solution to do this is the following:

```
 String tmp = "12345";
      int result = 0;
      for (int i =0; i < tmp.length(); i++){
          char digit = (char)(tmp.charAt(i) - '0');
          result += (digit * Math.pow(10, (tmp.length() - i - 1)));

      }

      System.out.println(result);
```

What I don't understand is why is:

```
char digit = (char)(tmp.charAt(i) - '0');
```

How can this convert into a digit?

Comment: Are you simply trying to convert a string to an int?

Comment: yes I am.. and I'd have to write my own function, kind of an atoi in C

Comment: Is this homework? If not, just use `Integer.valueOf("12345")`. If it is, please tag it as such.

Comment: @xonegirlz - did you try my solution? If it worked then please accept the answer and vote up!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: If @PTBG is right and you want to convert Strings to Ints, this question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java

Answer (score 14):

> char digit = (char)(tmp.charAt(i) - '0');

In the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), characters from `'0'` to `'9'` are contiguous. So, if you know that `tmp.charAt(i)` will return a character between `0` and `9`, then subracting `0` will return the offset from zero, that is, the digit that that character represents.

Answer (score 12):

Using Math.pow is very expensive, you would be better off using Integer.parseInt.

You don't have to use Math.pow. If your numbers are always positive you can do

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length(); i++)
   result = result * 10 + tmp.charAt(i) - '0';
```

Answer (score 7):

`char` is an integer type that maps our letters to numbers a computer can understand (see an [ascii chart](http://www.asciitable.com)).  A string is just an array of characters.  Since the digits are contiguous in ascii representation, `'1' - '0' = 49 - 48 = 1`, `'2' - '0' = 50 - 48 = 2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("12345") 
// or 
Integer number = Integer.valueOf("12345")
```

`atoi` could be a bit mistery for developers. Java prefers more readable names

Answer (score 1):

If using Integer.parseInt you have to catch exceptions, since 
Integer.parseInt("82.23") or Integer.parseInt("ABC") will launch exceptions.

If you want to allow things like

```
     atoi ("82.23") // => 82
     atoi ("AB123") // => 0
```

which makes sense then you can use

```
     public static int atoi (String sInt)
     {
        return (int) (atof (sInt));
     }

     public static long atol (String sLong)
     {
        return (long) (atof (sLong));
     }

     public static double atof (String sDob)
     {
        double reto = 0.;

        try {
           reto = Double.parseDouble(sDob);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

        return reto;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If programming  in Java, please use this,

```
int atoi(String str)
{
    try{
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
        return -1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is correct and - imho - answers the question, it qould benefit from more contextual information like, what `parseInt()` is, what it does, and where one can find it's documentation.

Comment: Sure. Static method `parseInt()` verifies if characters in string are decimals except for first one, which could be minus sign. [link]https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Comment: Please use the edit functionality on your question. See [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a built in function that does this...

```
String s =  "12345";
Integer result = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I echo what Tom said.

If you are confused with the above implementation then you can refer the below simpler implementation.

```
private static int getDecValue(char hex) {
    int dec = 0;
    switch (hex) {
    case '0':
        dec = 0;
        break;
    case '1':
        dec = 1;
        break;
    case '2':
        dec = 2;
        break;
    case '3':
        dec = 3;
        break;
    case '4':
        dec = 4;
        break;
    case '5':
        dec = 5;
        break;
    case '6':
        dec = 6;
        break;
    case '7':
        dec = 7;
        break;
    case '8':
        dec = 8;
        break;
    case '9':
        dec = 9;
        break;
    default:
        // do nothing
    }
    return dec;
}

public static int atoi(String ascii) throws Exception {
    int integer = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < ascii.length(); index++) {
        if (ascii.charAt(index) >= '0' && ascii.charAt(index) <= '9') {
            integer = (integer * 10) + getDecValue(ascii.charAt(index));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Is not an Integer : " + ascii.charAt(index));
        }
    }
    return integer;
}
```